# How we can bring almost similar and similar matches at the very top of the list against Tockenized Field Search- Apache Solr

Tags: solr

I have defined the following fieldType for my searchField:

Search is returning expected results. But I need to get almost similar and similar matches at the very top of the list. How we can achieve this with Apache Solr. Please help.

```
<fieldType name="SearchTokenizer" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
   <analyzer type="index">
     <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15"/>
   </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory"/>
     </analyzer> 
 </fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Query-time boosts are applied when constructing a search query, and apply to specific fields.

Query boosts are applied by appending the caret character ^ followed by a positive number to query clauses.

```
title:apple OR (title:apple AND title:Orange)^2.0 OR title:"apple Orange"^10
```

Here is link which give more details info on the boosting...
[detailed boosting information](http://nolanlawson.com/2012/06/02/comparing-boost-methods-in-solr/)

Comment: How we can decide the value of this query boost factor followed by caret character?

Comment: @ Abhijit Bashetti:  ie., it will work for the search values against two or more fields. Right? Think that, i have itemName field and i am defining ngram-ized type for the same, if i am searching for samsu--> this may be tokenized as sam, sa ,su,sams,us and so on....this will return records against these tokens, ie like samhello,suhai,samurai,samsung..in these values almost similar is samsung and that should come at the very top.

Comment: @Niranjan : I don't think that's possible ...Lets wait if someone else could know more on the same...Because you query should have samsung in it ...then only it can be boosted and brought on the top...

Comment: @MatsLindh: can you please help on this